# PHP send part of form under a certain condition

Tags: php, html

I have a search form through which users can, well, perform searches. When the "advanced search" checkbox is checked, a new part of the form shows, allowing for full customisation of the search. For a multitude of reasons, I have decided to send the form using the "get" method, thus displaying all variables in the url.

Problem is, when submitting a non-advanced search, the variables from the advanced part are still sent using the get method, making for a lengthy URL when it is not needed, as the advanced variables aren't used by the PHP that handles the search.

To hide the advanced form when the "advanced search" checkbox isn't checked, I've put the advanced form in a div of its own and have JavaScript set its style.display to "none" when the checkbox isn't checked, and have it reset to default when it is.

How would I best go about submitting only part of the form when "advanced search" isn't checked? A form within a form, removing and re-writing the div's content instead of simply hiding it, or what? Or is there an easy trick to this nobody's told me about?

Thanks!

Comment: If statement.http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561798/how-do-i-prevent-empty-get-variables-from-displaying-in-the-url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should probably use the attribute

```
<input disabled="disabled" ..
```

on the input fields when you do not want to submit them

you can find more information in [this article](http://kreotekdev.wordpress.com/2007/11/08/disabled-vs-readonly-form-fields/)

you will probably need to keep your "display:none" as the rendering of disabled elements depends on the browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you take the part where you do the `display:none` and add a piece where you set all the form-fields to `disabled` you'll be set.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use two forms, one for a simple search and one for an advanced search.

If the 'advanced' search is selected, hide the simple search and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think you use a Ajax (Jquery) part and load the Advance part. So from the server side you easily retreive. If you post your code part we can give a clear answer. thank you